# Fibonacci sequence c prog

Tags: c, fibonacci

I have a problem with C programming. I want to reach large numbers of fibonacci sequence but program, 47 Number of minutes to give the error. Here is the preview.

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
**-1323752223**
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried.

Comment: All the `int` types in C have an upper bound on the numbers they can compute.  Even a 64-bit `unsigned long long` doesn't take long to overflow.  If you want much bigger numbers, you need to look to multi-precision arithmetic libraries such as the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library ([GMP](http://gmplib.org)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want really large numbers you can use an array to store the digits of the fib as it is calculated

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you rolled over the limit for a 32 bit integer. Try using a 64 bit integer.

Comment: 64-bit *unsigned* integer, perhaps...  `unsigned long long`

Comment: Making the value unsigned will only give one additional iteration before overflow sets in (as compared to a signed value of the same width).

Comment: Well the max value of a 64 bit int is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (unsigned is double that). The barrier the user apparently hit was 2,147,483,647. It looks like you would get more than just 1 more iteration, but yeah, the point remains that you can only go so far. The user will just have to decide what he wants the upper boundary of his calculation to be and with what precision. If you use a floating number you have a higher limit, but you lose precision at large values.

Comment: i have already try that one, the problem still persists
can you please code a fibonacci sequuence C that i can enter values bigger than 50.